# calling to ziptastic API not giving me any information back

Tags: jquery, html

I was testing out ziptastic and set up my form and script based off a tutorial. Not working though and I was wondering if anyone knew why that could be?

When I type into the input forms on the page. Nothing comes back. All input boxes stay blank.

```
<input type='image' src='images/phm2.png' class='mainbut'>
<br>
<br>
<input type='text' placeholder='ZipCode' name='zipCode' id='zipCode'>
<input type='text' id='city' name='city'/>
<input type='text' id='state' name='state'/>

    </div>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ziptastic.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$document.ready(function () {


    $('#zipCode').keyup(function(e){
        var zipCode = $(this).val();
    if(zipCode.length === 5 && $.isNumeric(zipCode)) {
        var requestURL = 'http://ZiptasticAPI.com/' + zipCode +'?callback=?';
        $.getJSON(requestURL, null, function(data) {
            console.log(data);

            if(data.city) $('#city').val(data.city);
            if(data.state) $('#state').val(data.state);
        });
    }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "not working". Being specific makes you question much better!

Comment: It is not retrieving anything. The input forms just stay blank when i type in the zipcode.

Comment: You can (and should) [edit] that into your question.

Comment: Ok, Just did that. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: No, I know nothing about jquery, I'm just giving you tips to make your question better for folks who come along who do.

Comment: Ok, Thanks again. I sometimes rush through these question and forget. Sorry again

Comment: Anyone? Some help would be awesome

Comment: I know this is old but you aren't actually using the jquery plugin, you are making a JSON request to ziptasticapi.com which is not the same service/backed that is used by Ziptastic the service.